# How to omit results with date subquery on Laravel Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a Laravel app that has a table of models and a table of dates they're booked out. Only models who have entered dates they're booked out will have dates in the dates table. The dates are stored day by day. So the schema looks like the following (simplified):

**tbl_models**

```
 id   | name         | details         | gender    
 1    | joe bloggs   | over 60         | male           
 2    | jill bloggs  | pink nails      | female
 3    | a n other    | greying         | male
```

**tbl_ModelCalendar**

```
 id   | model_id  | date  
 1    | 1         | 2020-06-05 00:00:00         
 2    | 1         | 2020-06-06 00:00:00
 3    | 1         | 2020-06-07 00:00:00
 4    | 3         | 2020-09-15 00:00:00
```

I want to be able to select models based on those that *aren't* booked out within a certain date range. So, we feed in a **NotBookedOutFrom** date object and a **NotBookedOutTo** date object and return any models that are available between those two dates. I think I need a subquery for this? I can't INNER JOIN the bookings table because it then omits any models that don't have any booked out dates (i.e. are free all the time - ideal!) and I can't LEFT JOIN because it will return a result based on another available date outside of the scope of dates we've omitted.

At the moment, the code block from my controller looks like this:

```
$model->select('tbl_models.*');

$from =  DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', Carbon::parse($NotBookedOutFrom)->format('Y-m-d'));
$to =  DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', Carbon::parse($NotBookedOutTo)->format('Y-m-d'));
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($from, $interval, $to);

$model->leftJoin('tbl_ModelCalendar', 'tbl_ModelCalendar.model_id', '=', 'tbl_models.id');

$bookedDates = array();
      foreach ($period as $dt) {
          $thisDate = $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
          $bookedDates[] = $thisDate;

      }

$model->whereNotIn('tbl_ModelCalendar.date', [$bookedDates]);
```

Anyway, needless to say, this doesn't work and is a mess. I'm definitely missing something quite simple here but I've run around in circles for hours.

**EDIT:**

On the suggestion of Akina, I've tried to translate his answer to Query Builder but it's still not excluding booked out models:

```
$model->leftJoin('tbl_ModelCalendar', 'tbl_models.id', '=', DB::raw("tbl_ModelCalendar.model_id AND tbl_ModelCalendar.date BETWEEN $from AND $to"));
$model->whereNull('tbl_ModelCalendar.model_id');
```

Comment: After applying the contdition by `tbl_ModelCalendar.date` in WhereNotIn your LeftJoin become InnerJoin. This condition must be a part of joining condition.

Comment: Thanks @Akina. Does this mean just removing the leftJoin() above? This still doesn't get around the fact that if the user chose models available between 6th and 7th June it would return a result for model 1 because they are available on 5th June.

Comment: *Does this mean just removing the leftJoin() above?* In practice I'd recommend to create correct query using pure SQL then convert it into Laravel form.

Answer (score 0):

In pure SQL your query looks like

```
SELECT tbl_models.*
FROM tbl_models
LEFT JOIN tbl_ModelCalendar 
    ON tbl_models.id = tbl_ModelCalendar.model_id
   AND tbl_ModelCalendar.`date` BETWEEN @NotBookedOutFrom AND @NotBookedOutTo 
WHERE tbl_ModelCalendar.model_id IS NULL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=da8a24b084027241ffec7c4f9b95ca5c)

Comment: Thanks @Akina. I don't think this is right? This will display models that AREN'T available between those dates. I need to exclude models if the dates are present in that table and match the date range provided.

Comment: @TheEgg Pay attetion to `WHERE tbl_ModelCalendar.model_id IS NULL`. This means that we select records which do NOT match joining condition.

Comment: Thanks Akina. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. Translated that to:

$model->where(function($query) use ($from,$to){
                   $query->whereBetween('date',array($from,$to));
              });
          $model->whereRaw('tbl_ModelCalendar.model_id IS NULL');

But still returns models who are booked out.

Comment: @TheEgg Fiddle added. Output matches the conditions - look. The timerange borders are transferred via UDVs.

Comment: Hi Akina. Thank you for your continued help. I've updated my question with my attempt at translating your SQL to Query Builder but it still returns models that are booked out, unfortunately.

Comment: @TheEgg Convertion from pure SQL to Laravel seems to be the second task... I'd recommend you to post another question - the chance that somebody except me will help in this subtask seems to be low, whereas I do not know Laravel good enough for to help you.